# Jobs not deleting after completion with ttlSecondsAfterFinished

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service that deploys thousands of short lived jobs on Kubernetes each day. I am trying to get Kubernetes to delete these jobs after completion using the functionality described here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically

The job completes, but the Job remains in the cluster after the time limit expressed in `ttlSecondsAfterFinished`.

I'm testing this on GKE and my master node is running `1.12.7-gke.25`
I understand this is an alpha feature, but I haven't gotten a single Job to be deleted.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1 
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ttl-test
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ttl-test 
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: myimage
```

Comment: Do you have alpha features enabled on your GKE cluster? You can check this on the GCP console UI under Clusters / <your_cluster> / Details / Kubernetes alpha features.

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Comment: Let me move it to an answer then to help others in the future

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Kubernetes v1.21 the [TTL Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/) is in beta and enabled by default.

Until Kubernetes v1.20 it was an alpha feature. If you want to use it with a Kubernetes version older than v1.21, make sure alpha features are enabled on your GKE cluster. You can check this on the GCP console UI under Clusters / <your_cluster> / Details / Kubernetes alpha features.

Comment: Any update if this is still Alpha? K8s 1.12 was a while ago.

Comment: The link is actually pointing to latest, 1.20 at the moment. It's still alpha.

Comment: Is beta in 1.21 now and enabled by default.

Comment: it is stable feature in v1.23

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and My k8s version :1.20

Open this two file and add this command:

--feature-gates=TTLAfterFinished=true

First open: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml And add above comman, like :

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --feature-gates=TTLAfterFinished=true
```

After 5min open this file : /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml And add command again

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --feature-gates=TTLAfterFinished=true
```

After that, this two pod reset and after it’s ok and ready to use :)

Note:if you have cluster with multy master,do this on all of masters